# How to print the content between the third and the forth double quotation marks

Tags: text-processing, json

I have some logs from a web service on a Linux machine. The logs look like this:

```
{"log":"[2023-03-09T06:39:10.669Z] \"GET /server/prod?blank=true HTTP/1.1\" 200 - 0 874 1 1 \"-\" \"-\" \"aaad-bbb-ccc-dd-eeeee\" \"example.com:22213\" \"172.16.2.1:10080\"\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-03-09T06:39:11.935831787Z"}
```

As you can see, there are some double quotation marks. I need to print the content between the third and forth double quotation marks and between the 11th and 12th double quotation marks. Meaning that I want to get the content as below:

```
"GET /server/prod?blank=true HTTP/1.1\"   "example.com:22213\"
```

I just care about the contents. I don't care about `"` or `\`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By my count, you want the text between the fourth and fifth double quotes, and then between the twelfth and thirteenth:

```
sed -E 's/^([^"]*"){4}([^"]*")([^"]*"){8}([^"]*").*$/"\2   "\3/'
```

(using `sed` with support for extended regular expressions like GNU, various BSDs or Busybox) or

```
sed 's/^\([^"]*"\)\{4\}\([^"]*"\)\([^"]*"\)\{8\}\([^"]*"\).*$/"\2   "\3/'
```

(using any `sed`).

Comment: @Philippos, [GNU supports both `-r` and `-E`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html#Command_002dLine-Options), and so does Busybox, FWIW (but I never seem to find an online manual for it). But yes, `-E` is more common.

Comment: @ilkkachu GNU `sed` did originally support only `-r`, than added `-E` as hidden alternative without mentioning in the `man` page. After `-E` had been accepted, it's the recommended option in GNU `sed`, with `-r` being supported for backwards compatibility. I'm not sure when Solaris, AIX and HP-UX plan to add support.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), you can extract and decode the value of the `log` key:

```bash
$ jq -r .log file
[2023-03-09T06:39:10.669Z] "GET /server/prod?blank=true HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0 874 1 1 "-" "-" "aaad-bbb-ccc-dd-eeeee" "example.com:22213" "172.16.2.1:10080"
```

This is essentially a header-less CSV record using a space character as field separator, so we can use a CSV-aware tool like [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to parse out the 2nd and 12th field from this:

```bash
$ jq -r .log file | mlr --csv -N --fs space cut -f 2,12
"GET /server/prod?blank=true HTTP/1.1" example.com:22213
```

To make this easier to parse, you may want to use TSV output format:

```bash
$ jq -r .log file | mlr --c2t -N --ifs space cut -f 2,12
GET /server/prod?blank=true HTTP/1.1    example.com:22213
```

The quotation marks are removed automatically by Miller as the first field no longer contains embedded delimiters.

Note the change of `--csv` to `--c2t` (the same as `--icsv` together with `--otsv`) and also from `--fs` to `--ifs` (only sets the *input* field separator, not the output field separator).  In this case, changing `--fs space` to `--ifs space --ofs tab` would have had the same effect as Miller treats TSV and CSV the same (it's just the field separator that is different).

Answer (score 1):

One sample `awk` script can do the work. This uses the `"` character as the field separator, so the first field (`$1`) is the part before the first `"` etc.

```
awk -F\" '{print $5 " " $13}'
```

If you want to remove the backslashes too, you can do that with e.g. `gsub()` in the script:

```
awk -F\" '{gsub(/\\/, ""); print $5 " " $13}'
```

Comment: @Kusalananda, right, corrected. About space - I usually prefer to set the format a bit visual and by hand :)

Comment: The thing about `print $5" "$13` is that the quotes just look _wrong_, when you're used to shell or Perl where you wrap the quotes _around_ things like `"$foo"`... At least in AWK you could instead do `print $5 " " $13` which looks at least a bit less wrong. :) Me, I might actually prefer `printf "%s %s\n", $5, $13`, which of course doesn't use `ORS` either...

Comment: @ilkkachu, they look wrong, edit it. And thanx for the `gsub` :)

Comment: People: please don't get into discussions about such minor aesthetic preferences. What "looks right" or "wrong" will always depend on what each of us is used to.